# Autohotkey get width of current active child window

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to write a script that moves mouse cursor to the center of active child window.

```
WinGetActiveStats, Title, Width, Height, X, Y
MouseMove, Width / 2, Height / 2, 0
```

Above does the trick for the Main window. However, I can't seem to find a way to grab the width and height of active child window so that I can move the mouse cursor to the center of child window.

This is very useful feature when using with softwares such as AutoCAD where you could have more than one child window open at any given moment.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
ControlGetFocus, cr, A ; get the focused(active) control(child window) of the active window
ControlGetPos, x, y, width, Height, %cr%, A ; get the position and dimensions of this control
MouseMove, % x + Width / 2, % y + Height / 2, 0
```

Comment: Wow Thanks! tried playing around with control but couldn't get it to work.. works like a charm. Thank you so muich!

Comment: Hey Oleg, can you explain why "A" does not need % wrapped around it like %cr% does?

Comment: @Rok A is literally the letter A and it means use the Active Window. `cr` is a variable, it doesn't have to be `cr` can be anything. in `ControlGetFocus` it's an output variable so just the name of the variable is required, when it's used in `ControlGetPos` `%cr%` is needed to use the contents of the variable, without `%` it will just try to operate on a control named cr which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for that! I also see that you used "%" for `% x + Width / 2` I read the doc for variables and couldn't find anything related. Does that tell AHK that what follows will be a variable? Thanks!

Comment: @Rok Yes, it changes a command parameter from traditional to expression syntax and then you can use variables directly without enclosing them in % signs or use any expression. `MouseMove` command actually can treat it's parameters as expressions without leading `%` so it was not needed in this case but I just added it out of habit(this is unusual almost all commands do need it). The following is the relevant documentation https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#retrieving

Comment: Thanks for all the help!!